# javascript:very simple validation does not working

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out why this is not working as i did everything correct.
This is a simple create a account form. I put validation code for some of the field like name, email and password. There are many other fields. but first i m trying this.

The like is here:
`jsfiddle`

and the code of HTML:
           
          First Name

```
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/>



        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname />          

        <input type="text" name="remail" id="remail" />


      New Pasword
     <input type="password" name="rpass" id="rpass"  />

       <input name="regis" type="submit" class="color2" id="id" value="Submit" />
```

The javascript code here:

```
     function validateRegis() {
//regex for fname and lname

var fname = $("#fname").val();

var lname = $("#lname").val();
  var patt_n = /[a-z]{2,20}/i;
//checking fname and lname for regex matching 
var ftest = patt_n.test(fname);
var ltest = patt_n.test(lname);

var remail = $("#remail").val();
var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\-]+[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

var test = filter.test(remail);
var rpass = $("#rpass").val();
var patt = /[a-z0-9~!@#$%^&*()_\ ]/i;
var test2 = patt.test(rpass);


if (fname === "" || ftest === false) {
    alert("Please provide first name!");
    $("#fname").focus();
    return false;
} else if (lname === "" || ltest === false) {
    alert("Please provide Last name!");
    $("#lname").focus();
    return false;

} else if (remail === "" || test === false) {
    // 
    alert("Please provide email in correct format!");
    $("#remail").focus();
    return false;

} else if (rpass === "" || rpass.length < 8 || test2 === false) {
    alert("Please provide password!");
    $("#rpass").focus();
    return false;

} else if ((fname !== "") & (lname !== "") & (remail !== "") & (test === true) & (rpass >= 8) & test2 === true) {

    return true;
}
}
```

It needs jquery to run the code.

Comment: Post your code here, not just a link to jsfiddle.

Comment: I know this is very easy question and i made successfully for demo login form.

Comment: @vinaysingh: Simplify your code and paste it here.

Comment: no link of the jsfiddle

Comment: And explain how it's not working.

Comment: first of all, try using jquery validation framework. its simple and most efficient

Comment: @varun this is very simple validation, no need to go for plugins that require much memory.if you know what is the problem. suggest me

Comment: i am amazed that people are interested in down vote the question, not interested in answering and solving problem. lol!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `validateRegis` function is not available in the global scope.

In the fiddle UI left side panel, 2nd select box select `No Wrap in body`, it works fine.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XTUwf/)

When you select `onLoad` there, all the scripts under the script frame is wrapped under a anonymous function, so your `validateRegis` method becomes a local member of that anonymous function. Thus that function will not be available when the function submit is called causing an `Uncaught ReferenceError: validateRegis is not defined` error being thrown.

Comment: if you find my question valuable for js beginner, vote my question. Thanks for your answer and suggestion. I understood now.

Comment: Sir, this is fine only for jsfiddle but in actual page i have no <code>onLoad</code> So, why it is not working there?

Comment: share your complete html and javascript

Comment: check your browser's console to see whether there is any error

Comment: sir, actually i am working my friend's code that is really messy. There are youtube videos links in frames and the problem code is    Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://localhost:8080/facebook/hp.php# from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/ry8GimM1tGk. Domains, protocols and ports must match

Comment: I have two forms on one page with <code>return validate</code> is this the error? but both have separate function to validate.